# Start values selected in a mat-select from angular material

Tags: angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-select

I have this select control in my form showing a list of years

```
interface Opcion {
 value: string;
}

years: Opcion[] = [];
now: Date = new Date();
actualYear: number = this.now.getFullYear();
yearsSelected: string[] = [(this.actualYear - 4).toString(), (this.actualYear - 3).toString(), (this.actualYear - 2).toString(), (this.actualYear - 1).toString(), this.actualYear.toString()];

getYears() {
 let year = new Date().getFullYear();
 for (let i = 1990; i <= year; i++) {
  this.years.push({ value: i.toString() });
 }
 this.years.push({ value: 'Ultimos 5 años' });
 this.years.push({ value: 'Todos' });
```

}

```
form [formGroup]="form">
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Años</mat-label>
    <mat-select multiple placeholder="Año" formControlName="año" [(value)]="yearsSelected">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year.value"
        [selected]="yearsSelected.includes(year.value)">{{year.value}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I would like the last 5 years to be selected by default, But no selected start year appears

[image]

If I try through form I can't do it either

```
formularioOriginal = {
 organismo: 'Todos',
 año: this.yearsSelected
};
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.formularioOriginal);
```

I get this error

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved

[image]

So that you can dynamically decide which values are or are not selected you must use the [(ngModel)] directive.